# Removing the last element of a sized list in Coq

Tags: coq

Consider the following type definition of a sized list:

```
Inductive listn: nat -> Type -> Type :=
| nil: forall {A: Set}, listn 0 A
| cons: forall {n: nat} {A: Set}, A -> listn n A -> listn (S n) A.
```

This is essentially the [`Vect`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr) type in Idris.

I am trying to define the `init` function for `listn`, which removes the last element.

My attempted implementation was virtually identical to the definition of `init` in Idris. Here it is in Idris:

```
init : Vect (S len) elem -> Vect len elem
init (x::[])    = []
init (x::y::ys) = x :: init (y::ys)
```

Transcribed into Coq:

```
Fixpoint init {n: nat} {A: Set} (l: listn (S n) A): listn n A :=
match l with
| cons x nil => nil
| cons x (cons y ys) => cons x (init (cons y ys))
end.
```

…but this fails with:

```
The term "nil" has type "listn 0 ?A"
while it is expected to have type "listn ?n ?S@{a0:=S}"
(cannot unify "?n" and "0").
```

I take it that Coq isn't able to see that the case necessarily implies that `n` is zero. This is a problem I keep running into – Coq isn't able to see the relationship between `n` and the list itself.

Hence my questions:

- How can `init` be implemented in Coq?
- Why does the Idris definition work in Idris but not in Coq? What is Idris doing behind the scenes that Coq isn't?

Comment: In Coq, these are called vectors too: https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.VectorDef.html and the definition you are looking for is trunc: https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.VectorDef.html#trunc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By itself, Coq is not very good for writing this kind of code, but you can use the [Equations plugin](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations) to make it simpler. Nevertheless, let us see how we can do it without external dependencies:

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.
(* Vector.t is equivalent to your listn type *)

Arguments nil {A}.
Arguments cons {A} _ {n}.

Fixpoint init {n: nat} {A: Set} (xs: Vector.t A (S n)): Vector.t A n :=
  match xs in Vector.t _ m return Vector.t A (pred m) with
  | nil => nil
  | cons x xs =>
      match xs in Vector.t _ m return Vector.t A m -> Vector.t A m with
      | nil      => fun _  => nil
      | cons _ _ => fun xs => cons x (init xs)
      end xs
  end.
```

This definition differs from yours in a few ways. First, we need to annotate the return type of `match` to explain how it depends on the length of the vector. The `in Vector.t _ m` part says that the return type is *generic* on the length of the vector -- we *cannot* assume that the length is of the form `S n`.

Second, we have to enumerate all cases of the data type: `match` is *always* exhaustive in Coq, even if some of the branches are unreachable due to typing information. Thus, I've included a case for `nil` in the first match.

Third, Coq cannot recognize that `init (cons y ys)` is a valid recursive call. We fix this by giving `cons y ys` a name, `xs`, before destructing it, and using `init xs` instead. There is a subtlelty, however. In `cons x xs`, the type of `xs` is `Vector.t A m` for *some* `m`, which may or may not be a successor, so we cannot call `init` directly. Instead, we first destruct `xs`, and perform the recursive call only on the `cons` branch. But because `match` is generic on its length argument, Coq does not see a connection between the length of `xs` inside and outside of `match`.  The solution is to perform what Adam Chlipala calls the *convoy pattern*: we make match return a function rather than a plain vector, and pass `xs` as an argument outside of the match. This way, the connection between the two lengths is not lost.

I don't know much about Idris, but my guess is that its type-checking algorithm is more complicated than Coq's, which is why it can tell that the analogous definition is valid. Coq's rules are quite simple (and limited), to be honest.